# Was Bernie Sanders' recent town hall on fox news in any way unusual?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, bernie-sanders

It seemed to me, that the town hall went unusually well for Bernie and it seemed, that FOX was actually very fair, maybe even suspiciously so towards him.

When comparing this town hall to previous town halls on Fox news, where they interviewed a democratic presidential candidate, did the town hall with Bernie Sanders differ in any obvious way, which would give him an advantage?

What I found very strange was all the cheering from the live audience. I thought, that most of the live audience would be right leaning and not inclined to cheer about democratic talking points.

Now, I am not trying to ask why that may be the case, but if it is the case, if this town hall was less biased than similar previous town halls. I Hope that makes this question answerable.

Comment: Are you looking for documented facts that prove it was unusual?  That may be hard to find.

Comment: It was very unusual. There was a point where the moderator interjected and asked the crowd if they really wanted government sponsored health care or something to that effect, and contrary to what the moderator expected, the crowd basically cheered and went f'ck yeah.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy what I also found odd, was that Bernie was allowed to basically have as much time to answer any question as he needed and was not interrupted, even when straying way off topic.

Comment: And for some reason, he seems to have been treated worse on cnn lol.

Comment: Relevant article : https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/fox-news-cant-stop-talking-about-bernie-sanders/

Comment: Unless a leaked internal memo comes out from fox news about why they did this, I doubt you'll get a conclusive answer. Conjecture points to "fox wanted more/better viewers and saw a way to get them", or "fox supported Sanders to promote the weak candidate" if you assume fox is self-interested and purely conservative. (as is the gist I get from the question)

Answer (score 6):

It's important to note that Fox Studios are in New York and sourcing local voters would likely get the response seen.  Bernie did take some minor flack for announcing he would be on Fox News, but he pointed out that the Democrats need to attempt to make inroads into media favored by Republicans to discuss issues that are not just "Trump is Bad".

Another reason is that Fox tends to hire journalists from both sides of the political spectrum and the particular moderator (Chris Wallace) is a highly respected journalist who previously worked for NBC and ABC before joining Fox in 2003.  Wallace is still a registered democrat (though he doesn't always vote for them in the general).

And he's not the only one in Fox's employ.  Shepard Smith doesn't have any major statements on politics but tends to report from angles that they typical Fox Viewer would not appreciate and in 2017 came out as gay.  Fox has also recently hired Donna Brazile who explicitly said she wasn't betraying her party but felt the job would allow her to better speak to the other side of the aisle on democratic positions.  Even Tucker Carlson was on CNN and MSNBC before being picked up by Fox (famous for being mocked by Jon Stewart's appearance on his co-hosted show... along with his co-host.).

Comment: *used to be* on another network or *used to be* a respected journalist doesn't really say much how people will behave now. Lou Dobbs eg used to be a respected journalist, but now he is mostly known for peddling far-right conspiracy theories. Carlson may have been on MSNBC, but now he is known for his white supremacism. People change (either who they are, or how they represent themselves).

Comment: Even if Fox Studios is in New York, the town hall was filmed in Bethlehem, PA.

Comment: @Brythan Bethlehem's district voted for Clinton in 2016 and a Democrat for the House in  2018.  It's also a district prone to flipping.  Still, let's reverse the situation... If CNN did a Town Hall with Trump, who's more likely to show up:  CNN's typical audience who would cheer for universal health care?  Or Trump Supporters, who would boo it?

Comment: I think there are other quite relevant points to take into consideration regarding current context. Fox News is currently perceived as something akin to state propaganda. And it's not even difficult to find arguments supporting that perspective. Surveys of knowledgeability among viewers have shown abysmal results for Fox News for years now, to the point that their viewers were answering more questions incorrectly than people that did not watch any news at all (?!!?!!) ([example](http://publicmind.fdu.edu/2012/confirmed/)). This notion of balance you attribute to this network seems untrue.

Comment: @Armatita - Of course, there's this was this study from 2017 which found Fox News had an almost even split of positive and negative stories about Trump's first 100 days https://shorensteincenter.org/news-coverage-donald-trumps-first-100-days/   You may be shocked to learn that the majority were still negative... which is not a characteristic of State Media I am aware of... and compared to everyone else,, it's not nearly as one sided.

Comment: @hszmv This last comment speaks volumes. Have you even read the article you linked? There are whole sections specifically comparing Fox News with the aggregation of all other outlets in the study, particularly because it's such an outlier. The number you cited (52%, so a very small majority) is about overall coverage. By your criteria you could also say Breitbart is also very balanced because it's the only news outlet that gives roughly 50% positive coverage to Adolf Hitler. Never mind the fact that there might be very good reasons to give the guy bad coverage.

Comment: @Armatita:  I'm going to have to ask you to cite articles to positive spins on Hitler in Breitbart articles.  I'm having my doubts to your claim that they have such a spin in Hitler's favor.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with "sourcing local voters would likely get the response seen."  I'm pointing out that "Fox Studios are in New York" is irrelevant to the town hall, as it wasn't filmed in New York and "local" voters would not have been from New York.  Overall, I agree with the contention that a Bernie Sanders town hall on Fox News is more likely, in general, to have Bernie Sanders supporters attending than Fox News watchers.  But that still doesn't have anything to do with "Fox Studios are in New York".  It would be equally true if they were in rural Idaho.

Comment: @Brythan:  I got that bit wrong... I didn't really check where it was filmed.

Comment: It's not a claim. I was (quite obviously) speaking figuratively. I'm not a reader of breitbart (again, quite obviously).

Comment: @armatita Nor any facts that do not support your fiction that  there isn't nuance and all people you don't agree with are worse than Hitler (obviously).  Also audience knowledge is not the same metric as reporting balance.   Equating the two is a false argument and never once did I claim anything about the intelligence of viewers of any news service, but the reporting and hiring practices.